# mongoose Is there any difference of performance between subdocument and global in this case?

Tags: performance, node.js, mongodb

case1

```
var MessageSchema = new Schema({
  text: {type: String, required: true}
});

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    ..
  messages: {type: [MessageSchema], required: false}
});

UserSchema.find({_id:id},'messages',function(err, messages){
  // case 1
});
```

vs

case2

```
var MessageSchema = new Schema({
  text: {type: String, required: true},
  userId: {type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true}
});
MessageSchema.find({userId:id}, function(err, messages){
  //case 2
});
```

I just know How mongodb manipulates these two method.

Comment: Thanks for -1 vote. Merry Christmas. whoever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presuming you are comparing approaches for finding all documents for a user.

In the first case the _id will be indexed automatically so the find will be fast and the messages will be loaded when the user document is.

In the second case assuming you add an index on message userID then the find will lookup the userID in the index and load all documents that match the userID.

So if you are optimizing for the find and access messages, the first case should always be faster.

However, if you are optimizing message add and you have a large number of messages and new ones are added frequently, in the first case the user document will be growing and moving. It may hit document size limits. A bigger document is being saved.

For more detail, look at this guide which has a good discussion of the tradeoffs between references and embedded documents.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/MongoDB-data-models-guide.pdf

I hope this helps.

Comment: I already choose case2. but your opinion is also informative :)